# Is the famous HPACK demo diagram wrong?

Tags: http-headers, http2, huffman-code, hpack

[image]

I was so much confused by `19` in the rightmost picture, which IMHO would be 4 [2].

The slide is from https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1r7QXGYOLCh4fcUq0jDdDwKJWNqWK1o4xMtYpKZCJYjM/edit#slide=id.gfd0e3427_048

[2] https://http2.github.io/http2-spec/compression.html#rfc.section.A

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes looks wrong to me too, and I agree it should be 4 for `:path` and not 19 for `accept`.

The presenter's book High Performance Browser Networking ([available online for free](https://hpbn.co/)) has [this in the HPACK section](https://hpbn.co/http2/#header-compression):

[image: HPACK header compression example]

Which, as you can see, did include the `accept` header so suspect they just made a typo when they simplified the example for the slides.

Comment: Thank! BTW, your book HTTP/2 in action helps me a lot!

Comment: Fantastic to hear! Things like that!